# Не могу импортировать с другого файла @dp.message_handler в Aiogram и чтоб handler вызывался с основного файла где запускается бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiohttp

вот часть кода и все мпорты которые есть у меня

DeamonBot.py

```
import random
import time
import config
import logging
import inspect
import re
import typing
import asyncio
import GamesScript
from GamesScript import *
from lists import whattodoDemonas
from lists import whattodoDemonwhat
from contextvars import ContextVar
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterable, Optional, Union
from babel.support import LazyProxy
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.filters import BoundFilter, Filter
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, Message, InlineQuery, Poll, ChatType
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import Text
from aiogram.types.input_media import InputMedia
from aiogram.types import ContentTypes
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram import __main__ as aiogram_core

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(message)s')


TOKEN2 = Bot(config.TOKEN2)
dp = Dispatcher(TOKEN2)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentTypes.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def new_member(message):
    for i in message.new_chat_members:
        await message.reply_voice('AwACAgQAAxkBAAMrXmfcP92jwswn2_L4oXOlAfalSogAAq8jAALgEEFTzYJIFkYKN-oYBA')
```

GameScrips.py

```
import random
import time
import config
import logging
import inspect
import re
import typing
import asyncio
from Daemonbot import dp
from lists import whattodoDemonas
from lists import whattodoDemonwhat
from contextvars import ContextVar
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterable, Optional, Union
from babel.support import LazyProxy
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.filters import BoundFilter, Filter
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, Message, InlineQuery, Poll, ChatType
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import Text
from aiogram.types.input_media import InputMedia
from aiogram.types import ContentTypes
from aiogram.types.message import ContentType
from aiogram import __main__ as aiogram_core

TOKEN2 = Bot(config.TOKEN2)

@dp.message_handler(commands='Caliber')
async def Caliber(message: types.Message):
    await TOKEN2.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.reply("Год выпуска обновления: 2020\n\
 Жанр: Action, MMOFPS, Симулятор, Shooter, Online\n\
 Разработчик: Wargaming.net\n\
 Издательство в России: Wargaming.net\n\
 Тип издания: Лицензия\n\
 Язык интерфейса: Русский\n\
 Язык озвучки: Русский\n\
 Таблетка: Не требуется\n\
 \n\
 Системные требования:\n\
 Операционная система: Windows 7 / 8 / 10 (64 bit)\n\
 Процессор: i3-4xxx и более\n\
 Оперативная память: 4 Гб+\n\
 Видеокарта: 1Gb+ / NVIDIA GeForce GT 9800+, AMD HD 55xx+\n\
 Свободное место на жестком диске: 10 Гб\n\n\
 [перейди чтоб начать играть](https://caliber.ru/join/6566_RU1?pub_id=458032_&xid=1a2da443cd6db7656a70f4e6928288ac&sid=SIDdSbumdlUdDXt4mbtLAo9ILKtwh692apMCua2uHHdfwHr39Rftll2yXOkQtxp6xos15BLYe6l703F7t63pDC-c74XRNJJTWPvj-JHmgzYqk6CM4iVowUi_B6X5ACRT9Zicp-9bMoM760o7w&enctid=c176pg7ejtuo&lpsn=Clbr%2FClassic_CIS_V3_THEIA-2165&utm_source=networks&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=l5zhg0st&utm_content=458032_)", parse_mode='Markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Проблемма в том что с `GameScript.py` не вызываеться  `@dp.message_handler(commands='Caliber')`
и как сделать чтоб не приходилось делать каждый импорт под каждую команду.

**Спасибо за помощь**

Comment: что такое aoigram? телеграм? другой месенджер?

Comment: Данил, ты не знаешь что такое Aiogram ???

Comment: интересно. ну это библиотека для ботов телеграмм

Comment: а я что сказал?...

Comment: да именно для ботов телеграмм

Answer (score -1):

У вас в файле GameScrips.py создается еще один instanse "bot" в этой строке:

```
TOKEN2 = Bot(config.TOKEN2)
```

Уберите ее